# Как вернуть массив из функций, и потом по этому значению найти максимальное значение?

Tags: python

Есть матрица и ее максимальное число для участка матрицы
Нужно вынести создание матрицы в отдельную функцию
а при нахождении максимального числа подставлять данные из функции, где матрица создается

Как вернуть массив из функций, и потом по этому значению найти максимальное значение?

```
n = 7

M = []  # матрица

for i in range(1, n + 1):
    line = []  # строка
    for j in range(1, n + 1):
        line = line + [randint(1, 100)]
    M = M + [line]

for i in range(0, n):
    for j in range(0, n):
        print(f" {M[i][j]:4d}", end="")
    print()

max_number = M[0][0]

for i in range(0, n):
    for j in range(0, n):
        if i >= j and j < n - i:  # определить лежит ли элемент выше побочной диагонали но ниже главной диагонали матрицы
            if M[i][j] > max_number:
                max_number = M[i][j]

print("максимальное число = ", max_number)
```

---

ну вот так работает

но мне надо разделить этот код на две функции, чтобы из второй вызывать первую и получать максимальное число

```
def matrix(n):
    n = 7

    M = []  # матрица

    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        line = []  # строка
        for j in range(1, n + 1):
            line = line + [randint(1, 100)]
        M = M + [line]

    for i in range(0, n):
        for j in range(0, n):
            print(f" {M[i][j]:4d}", end="")
        print()

    max_number = M[0][0]

    for i in range(0, n):
        for j in range(0, n):
            if i >= j and j < n - i:  # определить лежит ли элемент выше побочной диагонали но ниже главной диагонали матрицы
                if M[i][j] > max_number:
                    max_number = M[i][j]
    print("максимальное число = ", max_number)
    return (M, max_number)


    matrix(7)
```

Comment: вопрос не понятен - что мешает вернуть вашу матрицу из функции через `return M`?

Comment: не знаю как это сделать какой синтаксис?

Comment: сделать что именно - создать функцию или выдать какой-то результат?

Comment: создать функцию, вызвать ее и получить матрицу, потом из этой матрицы найти максимальное число, из этой функции которая на матрицу создает.

Comment: `def create_matrix(n): #создаете и заполняете матрицу return M`, `def print_matrix(M): # тут выводите матрицу на экран`, `def find_max(M): # находите максимум return max_number` - в чем проблема - если вы смогли тот код написать или это не ваш код?

Comment: как в функцию def find_max(M) передать параметр M так чтобы он начал отсчет с 0 ?

Answer (score 1):

зачем вы так коряво создаете матрицу?

```
M = []  # матрица

for i in range(1, n + 1):
    line = []  # строка
    for j in range(1, n + 1):
        line = line + [randint(1, 100)]
    M = M + [line]
```

почему бы не сделать так:

```
M = [[randint(1, 100) for _ in range(n)] for _ in range(n)]
```

а вместо

```
max_number = M[0][0]

for i in range(0, n):
    for j in range(0, n):
        if i >= j and j < n - i:  # определить лежит ли элемент выше побочной диагонали но ниже главной диагонали матрицы
            if M[i][j] > max_number:
                max_number = M[i][j]
```

можно

```
max_number = max(max(M[i][j] for j in range(n) if i >= j and j < n - i) for i in range(n))
```

Если вам надо вернуть матрицу и результат, то можно сделать через кортеж к примеру

```
def func(n):
    # тут вся логика работы

    return (M, max_number)
```

и теперь можно этим пользоваться

```
res = func(10)
```

`res[0]` - это матрица

`res[1]` - это найденное максимальное значение

Comment: мне нужно сделать отдельную функцию и выделить ее в модуль а потом вызвать  его в основном коде

Comment: сделал так и получил ошибку IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @Roddg, приведите код - у меня работало, возможно вы начинаете считать от 1 до n включительно, когда надо от 0 до n-1

Comment: привел код выше

Comment: в этой функции я делаю матрицу - def matrix(n):
    n = 7

    M = []  # матрица

    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        line = []  # строка
        for j in range(1, n + 1):
            line = line + [randint(1, 100)]
        M = M + [line]

    for i in range(0, n):
        for j in range(0, n):
            print(f" {M[i][j]:4d}", end="")
        print()
    return (M)

Comment: потом мне надо передать из той функции то что она вернула то есть матрицу в другую функцию, как это сделать?